# PHP - Include fails on simple php file

Tags: php

I am including a file in one of my other php files by doing this:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/send_notification.php');
```

The code of the file I am including looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "Here!";
if(false === function_exists('sendNotification')) {
    function sendNotification() {
        echo "I HATE THIS";
    }
}
echo "There!"
?>
```

The File is included as follows:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/send_notification.php');
echo "And Here!";
```

But its only echoing this:

```
Here!There!
```

What is going on?

Comment: Is there an error or warning showing up ?

Comment: Perhaps you do not SEE the text. By include you output it on the first line. You may call the function in a point of the script and the data is echoed in a place you do not see it (under a div perhaps). Check the text in the source.

Comment: To view the errors, add this at the very top of both your files and run it again: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: i don't think this i good practice, your function should return the string, and then you should make a echo sendNotification(); The only reason to directly echo text in an include file is for displaying headers etc, but then it's not in a function

Comment: I have tried to show the errors, but I am calling this PHP file from an Android device. So it does not output anything.

Comment: Where is the server located, on the android device? This is some very simple code that should just work, so i think there's some other issue going on.

Comment: Its a windows server that I bought. Somewhere in switzerland.

Comment: Maybe your server is not accessible at all from outside? What happens if you ping the domain or ip?

Comment: Well it works well when I just do the echo in the second file. Its just when I add the function that it fails to include it. Also I just pinged it. Its available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always wrap your function to check for it's existence to prevent issues when included. And remove the closing PHP tag `?>` from included files, to prevent end-of-line (EOL) [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) issues.

**send_notification.php**

```
<?php
if (false === function_exists('sendNotification')) {
    function sendNotification() {
        echo "I HATE THIS";
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/send_notification.php';
sendNotification();
//...
```

You should also only use `include_once` or `require_once` notation on function/config pages to prevent overriding/duplication of variable values/functions when used.

Comment: I have added the include_once. Check the updated question. I is still not working.

Comment: Your updated question doesn't show you calling `sendNotification()`

Comment: Yeah because it seems that that is not the issue. It does not even get to the third echo statement. Something must be going wrong before that.

Comment: remove the end `?>` from the send_notification.php. I am guessing an `EOL` issue.

Comment: Jesus Christ. Thank you my friend. That fixed it. What is EOL? Did it insert the other php file and just end the one that I was inserting into?

Comment: EOL is end of line. The issue is that you had an extra end of line character at the end of the script causing parsing issues. eg `?>\r\n` removing the end `?>` prevents PHP from parsing the `\r\n` as content and assumes it is PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
    function sendNotification() {
        return "I HATE THIS";
    }
?>

echo sendNotification();
```

Comment: Then how do I call the function from outside of the file?

Comment: If you return it or not doesn't make a difference

Comment: I tried this. It does not even get to the call. The include seems to just fail when I have the function in there.