# Why require(local_file) or include(local_file) may fail & how to handle that?

Tags: php

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file;
>   this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal
>   error.

However, there's nothing more about possible errors or error handling.

1. Does it mean that the only reason why `include` or `require` may fail is not being able to find the file? There might be any other reasons?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261756/how-to-catch-error-of-require-or-include-in-php) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327238/php-include-fails-on-simple-php-file) questions about fail handling.

So, considering I want to include another .php file stored on my server following best practices, and I write:

```php
if ( file_exists('myFile.php') ) {
    require_once 'myFile.php';
}
```

2. Can I consider this script to be completely "safe"? Will `myFile.php` always be included if it exists?

Comment: Usually scripts that are included are really needed: The application won't work without them. So making the inclusion optional seems very weird to me.

Comment: if the file you include does have PHP error the include will fail

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That's exactly why I have this question. If the only reason it might fail is absence of file, then it's possible to handle it somehow in the `else` statement & exit.

Comment: That's not what your code says. There's no `else` with an exit. But I get your point. You do realize that `require()` already does exit with an error? That's the behaviour you describe. I think it would be slightly more efficient to use `include()` in an `try ... catch`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369619/3986005). It doesn't need the extra `file_exists()` call.